# Как прописать путь к картинке в js файле при натяжке на Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Здраствуйте!
При верстке макета было необходимо при разном разрешении экрана добавлять разные картинки путем интеграции через js код.

Сейчас при натяжке этой верстки на WP не знаю как правильно прописать путь.
Если добавлять в html, то все понятно - это что-то типо такого

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/logo/logo.svg" alt="logo">
```

**Но как быть в такой ситуации ?**

```
if(screenWidth > 865) {
    $(".whoweare__rigth-content-img").attr("src", "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/rocket_group_main.svg");
} else if(screenWidth < 865 && screenWidth > 550 ) {
    $(".whoweare__rigth-content-img").attr("src", "src/images/rocket_group_768.svg");
} else {
    $(".whoweare__rigth-content-img").attr("src", "src/images/rocket_block_mobile.svg");
}
```

Как прописать путь к картинке в JS коде при натяжке на WP?

Comment: Ну наверное можно локализовать скрипт при помощи [wp_localize_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_localize_script) и в качестве параметра передать в JS файл `get_template_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 0):

1)Вам необходимо использовать тег [picture](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)
2)Дальше вам необходимо передавать значения которые привязаны к конкретным изображениям в медиазапросах в `srcset` Проще всего для этого использовать плагин для WP [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/).

```
 <picture class="post_image">
                    <source media="(min-width: 1420px)" srcset="<?php echo $imgBig ?>">
                    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="<?php echo $imgMiddle?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" width="450" height="360" alt="<?php echo $title ?>">
                </picture>
```

Comment: Во первых ТС спрашивал по js. А во вторых  - это извращение не нужно. Всё есть в ВП из коробки.

Comment: Можно и из коробки. А вот использование JS где это лишние килобайты пользователю... Вешать какой-то вотчер на изменение ориентации и размеров браузера. Ну такое... скорее всего автор вопроса пробует натянуть то, что уже сработало на технологию которая нова для его изучения.

Comment: Коллега, у ТСа именно такая задача (мы не знаем зачем ему так понадобилось, но возможно что и оправдано). А твой ответ никак не решение. (более того - ужасный костыль, который нельзя рекомендовать приличным людям)

Comment: Ребят, я новчиок во фронте и верстку на WP натягиваю второй раз. Проблема заключалась в том, что при адаптиве было необходимо менять одну картинку под разные дисплеи, поэтому задавал путь к картинке через js. Жаль что через @media css такого нельзя сделать

Answer (score 0):

Я подумал и в моей конкретно ситуации, где нужно просто в определенный блок вставлять определенную картинку под определенную ширину экрана, достаточно было обойтись CSS media. Возможно не самый лучший способ решения моей проблемы, но он черт побери действенный !!!
Просто задаю путь к картинке через атрибут background-image прописывая обыкновенный путь без php функций.

Надеюсь кому-то пригодится)